Не работает фикстура создания таблиц БД pytest
При запуске тестов фикстура prepare_database прогоняется, что видно в логах теста, но при этом таблицы в базе данных не появляются. Если вставить код из фикстуры непосредственно в тест, все работает, таблицы создаются. В чем может быть причина?
conftest.py
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
async def prepare_database(event_loop):
    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

test_place.py
async def test_create_model(event_loop):
    async with async_session_maker() as session:
        new_record = Place(
            id="93169ada-d374-4152-addb-322412e335a3", title="Test Record"
        )
        session.add(new_record)
        await session.commit()

        result = await session.get(Place, new_record.id)
        assert result is not None
        assert result.title == "Test Record"
    yield

    async with async_engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all)

Вывод теста
SETUP    S event_loop_policy
SETUP    S event_loop
SETUP    S prepare_database (fixtures used: event_loop)
       tests/unit/test_place.py::test_create_model (fixtures used: event_loop, ??event_loop_policy, prepare_database, request)```

